# Adding dynamically <li> in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-lists

I'm trying to add elements dynamically in an ul with ajax and my current code is this in ajax method:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
            ul.appendChild(li);
```

But it creates "standard" li elements, i want to create them in this type:

```
<li style="cursor:pointer;"><a onclick="javascript:$('#cod').val(array[i])">array[i]</a></li>
```

How can i do this?

[EDIT]
What i want to create is [**THIS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GacJt.png) (you can see that it appears a "shadow" that signify it is selectable

But jvascript creates this type of [**OPTIONS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKSmA.png),
now you can see that the options doesn't got that "shadow".

Comment: You can't add the dynamic elements like `<%=IDAnag%>` using javascript, because they will have been added to the page by the server before the javascript runs. You could store them in javascript variables and then have the javascript add them. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mikeyq6: Ooops.. I was answered but miss the asp tag

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the code, <%=IDAnag%> is stored in array[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself, if someone needed here is the code:

```
    var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    $("li").each(function()
    {
        var $li = $(this);
        $li.css("cursor","pointer");       
    });
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var l = array[i];
    a.textContent = array[i];

    a.addEventListener("click",function(){
    $("#cod").val(array[i]);
    });
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 0):

How i understand content for this `<%=IDAnag%>` insert your back end. And when you click on link this content has already been generated. Maybe you can try something like that:

```js
function AppendLi(val){
  var ul = document.getElementById("menu");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML= val;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<li style="cursor:pointer;">
  <a onclick="AppendLi(this.textContent)">
    <%=IDAnag%>
  </a>
</li>
<ul id="menu"></ul>
```

But I do not know how you have built the your backend. maybe best way add this event on backend side?

Comment: I included the images so you can undertand better